# Update blob column in INSERT trigger (Oracle 11g)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, blob

I'm using Oracle 11.0.2.3. I have a table with a BLOB column and this column stores a XML text. For this table, I made a BEFORE INSERT trigger and I'm able to view the blob column value (via :new.XML_BLOB) as expected. However when I change the XML data (in the trigger code) in the blob, it is not getting persisted into the BLOB column at all.

```
create or replace TRIGGER MY_TRIGGER
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON MY_TABLE
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_Buffer  varchar2(4000);
BEGIN

   if (INSERTING) then

      v_buffer := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(dbms_lob.substr(:new.XML_BLOB, 2000, 1)) || UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(dbms_lob.substr(:new.XML_BLOB, 2000, 2001));

      v_buffer := replace(v_buffer,'<id>Data</id>', '<id>New-Data</id>');

      :new.XML_BLOB := sf_convert_clob_to_blob(to_clob(v_buffer));

   end if;          

exception
    when OTHERS then
         RAISE;
end;
```

The function sf_convert_clob_to_blob is taken from here: [Copy current CLOB column to new BLOB column in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612181/copy-current-clob-column-to-new-blob-column-in-oracle).

How do I force the BLOB column changes via the INSERT trigger?

Thanks.

Comment: I just added the code sample - please check it.

Comment: Seems to work for me, in 11.2.0.4. I can't see any reason it wouldn't in 11.2.0.3. If I supply a BLOB created by that function from a string which includes `<id>Data</id>` then the inserted value (converted back) has `<id>New-Data</id>`. How are you inserting the data and how are you checking whether it worked?

Comment: The insert is done from Java application code (Camel with Hibernation).  The code can't be changed so I'm looking for a short-term solution via DB trigger option.  VARCHAR2 changes in trigger seems to work fine.

Comment: I'm checking via SQL Plus after the insert is committed.

Comment: But checking how - how are you converting the stored BLOB to a readable string? Anyway... is the Java code deleting and reinserting, and maybe not committing? What do you see when you do the insert from SQL\*Plus, so you're querying in the same session? Your trigger is working fine for me so something else seems to be going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108959/discussion-between-jkk-and-alex-poole).